# Xamarin.Forms Android save image to gallery

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a stream which is the result of taking a photo. I want to save that photo to the users Gallery.

I have tried all manner of things but nothing takes... The class I am saving is a plain C# class - it does not inherit form any android types but that could be done if necessary (to fire an intent perhaps - though I tried this and it ended up another rabbit hole)

I have tried this:

```
try{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + _name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
}
```

and also:

```
        if (_filename.ToLower ().Contains (".jpg") || _filename.ToLower ().Contains (".png")) {
            stream.Position = 0;
            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (stream);

            var finalStream = new MemoryStream ();

            bitmap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 25, finalStream);
            bitmap = null;

            finalStream.Position = 0;

            var path2 = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
            var filename2 = System.IO.Path.Combine (path2, _filename);

            using (var fileStream = File.Create (filename2)) {
                finalStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                finalStream.CopyTo (fileStream);
                fileStream.Close ();

                finalStream.Dispose ();
                stream.Dispose ();
                fileStream.Dispose ();
                GC.Collect ();
            }
            return;
        }
```

I thought this would be an easy task! meh...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MediaStore](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Provider.MediaStore+Images+Media/) [ContentProvider](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/).  [MediaStore.Images.Media](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Provider.MediaStore+Images+Media/) has several Insert methods you can use to add content to the gallery.

Comment: hmm getting this on those links: Error.

An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: the Xamarin API docs seems to be having issues right now - but this one should be working - http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/