# When download image to pictures directory it isn't being shown on gallery [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: android, xamarin, download, xamarin.forms, gallery

I'm using the code below to download images:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    var bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                          //string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/" + Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures + "/";
    string localFilename = img.Uri.LocalPath.Split('/').Last();
    string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(localPath);

    using (var os = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Truncate))
    {
        bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 95, os);
    }

};
webClient.DownloadDataAsync(img.Uri);
```

The problem is that the image is being shown on files but not on gallery. I'm running on android.

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296280/xamarin-forms-android-save-image-to-gallery

Answer (score 3):

You can manually trigger a MediaStore update via:

```
var pathToPublicImage = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/stackoverflow.png";

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(this, new string[] { pathToPublicImage }, null, this);
}
else
{
    using (var file = new Java.IO.File(pathToPublicImage))
    using (var uri = Uri.FromFile(file))
    {
        SendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile, uri));
    }
}
```

#### MediaScannerConnection.IOnScanCompletedListener

```
public void OnScanCompleted(string path, Uri uri)
{
    Log.Debug("SO", "Media Scan Finished, Open Gallery Now");
}
```

#### `Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile` Start/Finish

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionMediaScannerStarted, Intent.ActionMediaScannerFinished })]
public class MediaUpdates : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        switch (intent.Action)
        {
            case Intent.ActionMediaScannerStarted:
                Log.Debug("SO", "Media Scan Started");
                break;
            case Intent.ActionMediaScannerFinished:
                Log.Debug("SO", "Media Scan Finished, Open Gallery Now");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GiorgeCaique In your `Xamarin.Android` application project.

Comment: The error "SendBroadcast does not exist in the current context"  is being shown.

Comment: SendBroadcast : Use an Activity or Application level context

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Xamarin Forms development. I'm using an Interface on PCL project and the implementation is happening in iOS and Android projects. Can I still use an Activity working with the Dependency? Can you please post an example of this activity code?

Answer (score 0):

I founded a solution.

Just use this method:

```
private void UpdateGallery()
{
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(_path);
    Android.Net.Uri contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
    mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
    Application.Context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```