# Signature Pad Xamarin.Forms Saving signature as a file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, signature

I am a beginner in Xamarin.
I tried to write a simple app to save the signature with the help of Signature Pad.
A piece of code from MainPage.xaml

```
<controls:SignaturePadView x:Name="SignaturePAD"
                           Grid.Row="1" 
                           StrokeColor="Black" 
                           StrokeWidth="3"
                           BackgroundColor="Gray" 
                           CaptionTextColor="Black"
                           PromptTextColor="Black"
                           SignatureLineColor="Black"
                           CaptionText="Podpis odbiorcy">
</controls:SignaturePadView>

<Button Grid.Row="2" 
        x:Name="SaveButton"
        Text="Potwierdź" 
        Clicked="SaveSignature"/>
```

and a fragment from MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async void SaveSignature(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream image = await SignaturePAD.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);

    }

}
```

And my question is how can I save it into the my phone gallery?
I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 3):

the `SignaturePad` returns a stream - so you can write it to a file using normal C# I/O, like `FileStream`

```
Stream image = await SignaturePAD.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
{
  image.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, OP specifies that he is a beginner in Xamarin in his post. While this code may be a solution to the question, it would probably be helpful for OP and future visitors if you explain why this code is a solution to OP's issue (what they've done wrong and how this fixes it!).

Comment: Thanks this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find a plugin somewhere that would do this for you, but I would convert the `stream` to a `byte[]` like so:

```
using (image)
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    var picture = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Then convert the byte[] to the native picture on each platform.

For Android use:

```
BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.Length);
```

And for iOS use:

```
var nsData = NSData.FromArray(picture);
var uiImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(nsData);
```

Then you would need to add the image to the underlying gallery. Here is an example of how to achieve something like that on iOS: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/save_photo_to_album_with_metadata/

For Android, this post might help: [Xamarin.Forms Android save image to gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296280/xamarin-forms-android-save-image-to-gallery)