# how to draw smooth curve(Signature) in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, bitmap, skiasharp, touchtracking

I am trying to develop app which has drawing bitmap and saving it into file. I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/saving skiasharp example.

In iOS this works fine but for android its not the smooth and the curves are drawn in straight line.

Earlier I was opening the drawing page in shell but was facing issue with drawing after so I changed it to app mainpage.

I am now able to draw on android. But the drawing in not smooth and all curved edges comes in straight lines.

Can someone help?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.
[Signature Pad Xamarin.Forms Saving signature as a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907793/signature-pad-xamarin-forms-saving-signature-as-a-file][1])

This is better solution for capturing signature and storing into file.