# Saving bitmap to gallery in Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, bitmap, stream, android-external-storage

I thought that should be simple, yet I can't figure it out.
I keep getting the error: `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/name.jpg"`.

The code:

```
string root = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).Path;
File myDir = new File(root + "/Screenshots");
myDir.Mkdirs();

string timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").Format(new Date());
string fname = CommunicationHandler.GetNickname() + "|" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

File file = new File(myDir, fname);
if (file.Exists())
    file.Delete();
try
{
    using (System.IO.Stream outStream = System.IO.File.Create(file.Path))
        {
            finalBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outStream);
            outStream.Flush();
            outStream.Close();
        }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.MakeText(Activity, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Also, I can't access manually to /storage/emulated/0..

Why can't I manage to save the bitmap to my phone gallery? What's the problem in the code above?

Comment: Android has APIs for saving images to the gallery.  You can't just write to the filesystem to do it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296280/xamarin-forms-android-save-image-to-gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624756/how-to-save-bitmap-to-android-gallery):

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
}
```

Also, note that you could just add an image to the gallery via a simple line:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(applicationContext.getContentResolver(), IMAGE ,"nameofimage" , "description");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new directory, you can use  `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(root);` to create it.

```
//create a directory called MyCamera
    string root = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDcim).ToString() + "/MyCamera/";

   //create the Directory
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
```